# Noncommutative group of invertible ideals of a ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a noetherian domain and let $\mathcal{O}$ be an $R$-algebra that is finitely generated and projective as an $R$-module.  The set of invertible fractional ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ is a group under multiplication.  Is this group always abelian?

Comment: It looks like some of your post got cut off.  I also think you meant $R$-module, rather than $\mathcal{O}$-module.  Also, what is the definition you use for an invertible ideal in a non-commutative ring?

Comment: Thanks Pace!  (Something happened in the copy and paste, ugh.)  The definition of invertible is what it must be to make this into a group: a fractional ideal $I$ is invertible if there exists a fractional ideal $J$ such that $JI=IJ=\mathcal{O}$.  JV

Comment: What's a fractional ideal at all in a noncommutative ring?

Comment: @FernandoMuro $K$ being the field of fractions of $R$ and $A = K\otimes_R\mathcal{O}$, I would guess a fractional ideal is a lattice $I\subset A$ (finitely generated $R$-submodule with $KI=A$) with left and right order equal to $\mathcal{O}$. Does this work?

Comment: @Aurel: conventions differ, but you might ask only that $\mathcal{O}$ is contained in the left and right orders; if $I$ is invertible, then equality holds, so this doesn't matter for the question.  (@FernandoMuro: It is also equivalent to take a fractional ideal $I$ to be a $\mathcal{O}$-sub-bimodule of $K \otimes_R \mathcal{O}$ of the form $I=cJ$ where $c \in K^\times$ and $J \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ is a two-sided ideal.  Hence the ``fractional''.)

Comment: @Aurel and John Voight, what's the field of fractions of a noncommutative ring?

Comment: @FernandoMuro The base ring $R$ is assumed to be commutative: it is a domain.  So the field of fractions means what it usually does.  (There are notions of rings of quotients for noncommutative rings, but they don't play a role here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; it is not abelian in general.

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring with maximal ideal generated by an element $\pi$, let $k := R / \pi R$ be the residue field of $R$ and let $\mathcal{O}$ be the inverse image in $M_2(R)$ of the scalar matrices in $M_2(k)$. Note that $\mathcal{O}$ is free of rank $4$ as an $R$-module, with basis $\{e_{11} + e_{22}, \pi e_{11}, \pi e_{12}, \pi e_{21}\}$ say. So $\mathcal{O}$ is, in particular, finitely generated and projective as an $R$-module.

For every $g \in GL_2(R)$, you have the invertible fractional ideal $\mathcal{O}g$. Note that $\mathcal{O}g \cdot \mathcal{O} h = \mathcal{O} gh$ since $GL_2(R)$ normalises $\mathcal{O}$ inside $M_2(R)$. Note also that $\mathcal{O} g = \mathcal{O} h$ if and only if $gh^{-1} \in \mathcal{O}^\times$, which is the preimage in $GL_2(R)$ of the group of scalar matrices in $GL_2(k)$. So we obtain an injective group homomorphism from $PGL_2(k) \cong GL_2(R) / \mathcal{O}^\times$ into the group $I(\mathcal{O})$ of invertible fractional ideals of $\mathcal{O}$.

In the positive direction, if $K$ is the field of fractions of a Dedekind domain $R$ and if  $\mathcal{O}$ is a *maximal order* in some finite dimensional separable $K$-algebra, then $I(\mathcal{O})$ is abelian.

See Theorem 12 and Theorem 13(c) of [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-180-00/S0002-9947-1973-0318204-3/S0002-9947-1973-0318204-3.pdf) paper by Frőhlich, which gives a thorough discussion of the Picard group of a noncommutative ring.